# Why cant I send data through this ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hey guys I have been trying to hook up Html select element with ajax to change the language on my website. The idea is to send the value of select thought ajax to PHP file where I would then use that value as a session to include other PHP files with language variables.

Everything works ok, but for some reason, the PHP file is not getting the data from ajax.

So here is the code:

HTML:

```
  <div class="lang langMobile" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0px);" >
              <div data-uk-form-custom="target: true" class="uk-form-custom">
      <select class="custom-select custom-select-mobile"id="language_custom-select">
<option class="custom-option" hidden> <?php echo $_SESSION['lang']?></option>
<option class="custom-option" value="En"> En</option>
            <option class="custom-option" value="Bs">Bs</option>
     </select>

       </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#language_custom-select').change(function() {
    var optionValue =  $('#language_custom-select').val();
    console.log(optionValue)
    $.ajax({
        url:'switch.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {selected: optionValue},
    }).done(function(data) {
        window.location.reload();
    })
})
```

PHP:

```
   if(isset($_POST['selected'])) {
              
            $_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['selected'];

        } else if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
            $_SESSION['lang'] = "En";

            
        }
 
   include "include/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";
```

Comment: have you get value in var `optionValue` ?

Comment: Yes. It changes in console.log.

Comment: have you get the value of `echo $_SESSION['lang']` in console.log.

Comment: If you are going to be playing around with the global `$_SESSION` variable you probably need to call `session_start()` function at the (very) top of your php file to continue that session. Are you currently doing that?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot to copy session_start(), but I am using it.